# Add item into shopping cart of magento

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

I am using Magento-1.7 for client's website, the requirement is that he wants the products from API, Product edit/add etc. are handle by API. We only display the resulted product on our site.

Now problem is that how i add the final product(generated by API) to magento shopping cart.

Explain in detail, i am new in Custom module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be asking about adding product in cart programatically. If so following is answer:

```
$cart =Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->addProduct($product, array('qty'=>$qty)); 
$cart->save();
```

Add those code in your Custom Module.

Comment: i am using qty array with product id like this : array('product' =>  $productid ,'qty' => $qty), working fine

Answer (score 0):

You have to use web services under `system->config` to link your API.

The API should be programmed to transfer data from the third party system (Your client system) to your magento site database